# jQuery.animate scroll issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a problem with animating a font when is scrolls past the viewport height. It can animate once but not back again...

This works, it just changes the font size back and forth:

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height()) {
               $('.nav li a').css({"font-size":"2vw"});
            } else {
               $('.nav li a').css({"font-size":"1.2vw"});
            }
```

But this does not, it animates once but then starts to lag and jump when it should animate back:

```
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height()) {
               $('.nav li a').animate({"font-size":"2vw"});
            } else {
               $('.nav li a').animate({"font-size":"1.2vw"});
            }
```

Does anyone know why?
Thanks!

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: The animate part is ok, just tried http://jsfiddle.net/DL9Hv/

But the problem might be: **when** are you calling this code? You do not want to continuously call animate in a loop. Just call it when the `$(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height()` state has changed

Comment: I'm calling the code when the scrollTop value is larger than the value of the viewport height.

Comment: Yes, but when are you testing for it? if it is in a loop or on an event, etc.. be careful not to call animate 1000 times

Comment: `var oldState=newState; var newState=$(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height(); if(oldState!=newState) { if(newState) {...animate...} else {...animateback...} }`

Comment: This code changes the size of the font as soon as I start scrolling :/

Comment: because newState is not inited, so the test at first returs true. you should set `var newState=$(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height();` outside of the scroll event (at page loaded) and remove the var before newState inside the scroll event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this need to be animated in jQuery? You can get your effect with CSS3 transitions (unless you're trying to support older browsers):

```
transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

Or font only:

```
transition: font 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: font 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: font 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: font 0.3s ease;
-ms-transition: font 0.3s ease;
```

You can then use the .css() method to change font-size and the CSS transition will handle the animation.

Comment: I used jQuery to animate when the user scrolls past a specific point. Can I do that without jQuery?

Comment: You can use the above CSS code and use your first jQuery function (the one using the .css() method), it will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case the problem is you calling animate too many times, you may try something like this (untested code, sorry I can't try it now):

```
var newState=$(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height();


function updateOnScroll(e) {

    var oldState=newState;

    newState=$(this).scrollTop() > $( window ).height();

    if(oldState!=newState) {
        if(newState) {
            $('.nav li a').animate({"font-size":"100vw"});
        } else {
            $('.nav li a').animate({"font-size":"1.2vw"});
        }
     }
}
```

Just an idea...